# Lists are not displaying- only empty brackets

Tags: list, python-2.7

I'm attempting to create a recognition task. I have a .txt file which houses ~600 words. From this list, I'm trying to create sub-lists (e.g. List1, List2.) For some reason, I cannot get the words from the sub-lists to appear. It's only returning []. Please help!!

```
wordNum = 0

# Create list
wordList = []
with open('mfwords.txt','r') as f:

    for line in f:

        wordNum = wordNum+1

    for word in line.split():

        wordList.append(word)

 # Shuffle list
import random

random.shuffle(wordList)

# Number of words in list
listLen = 50

# List 1 is first 50 words of wordList
list1 = wordList[0:50]

# List 2 is first 100 words of wordList
list2 = wordList[0:100]
```

Comment: Try to keep your imports at the top of the file. You'll thank yourself later when you don't have to search through the whole file to know what's defined there.

Answer (score 3):

Your `with open` block doesn't look right to me. The second `for` needs to be within the first, or else it will only execute when `line` is pointing to the very last line in the file. Try:

```
with open('mfwords.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
            wordList.append(word)
```

Comment: That worked! Seems the indentation was changed when I pasted the code. Thank you!